# Change data type/constraint of column

Tags: sql-server

I have an existing column `people` that contains a column `pid`. I would like to alter `pid` from:

- int -> 5 character long string
- unique -> unique within `pid` and `company_id` (foreign key)

I am currently not using `pid` in my mssql database so I can drop that column. My understanding is that I would have to break my tasks down into three steps:

1. Drop column
2. Add column
3. Add uniqueness to column

Would my mssql statement look like:

```
ALTER TABLE people DROP COLUMN pid;
ALTER TABLE people ADD pid VARCHAR(5);
ALTER TABLE people ADD CONSTRAINT unique_pid UNIQUE (pid, company_id);
```

I have executed the above mssql statement but I do not see the `pid` column in my `people`. I don't notice any errors being thrown and I want to verify that my statement is correct before I dive deeper.

Comment: So, what is your question here exactly? If it's "Will the SQL above work?" Have you tried it (perhaps in a Development environment)? If not, why not? Go and try it (again, use a development environment first, it's what they're for)! If yes, and it *did* work, what's the question? If it didn't work, what was the problem?

Comment: @Larnu - Woops, I forgot to add my question. I have tried my statement but I do not see the `pid` column anymore. I also didn't see any errors either.

Comment: Did you refresh SSMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine the problem is that the batch failed. The likely  reason being is you'll need to set a value for `pid` prior to creating the `CONSTRAINT`. If you have any data in your table and `company_id` isn't unique then you'll have duplicate values. So, as a quick example, the following will work:

```
CREATE TABLE #people (pid int, company_id int)
GO

SELECT *
FROM #people;
GO

ALTER TABLE #people DROP COLUMN pid;
ALTER TABLE #people ADD pid VARCHAR(5);
ALTER TABLE #people ADD CONSTRAINT unique_pid UNIQUE (pid, company_id);
GO

SELECT *
FROM #people;
GO

DROP TABLE #people;
```

If, however, I put some data in the table first, the batch will fail:

```
CREATE TABLE #people (pid int, company_id int)
GO

INSERT INTO #people (company_id)
VALUES (1),(1),(2);
GO
SELECT *
FROM #people;
GO

ALTER TABLE #people DROP COLUMN pid;
ALTER TABLE #people ADD pid VARCHAR(5);
ALTER TABLE #people ADD CONSTRAINT unique_pid UNIQUE (pid, company_id);
GO

SELECT *
FROM #people;
GO

DROP TABLE #people;
```

In this case, I actually still had the column `pid`, but, the `CONSTRAINT` failed. Depending on where you had your transaction, it may well have been that the `DROP` committed, however, the `ADD` was rolled back with the `ADD CONSTRAINT`.

To fix the problem, you'll need to first populate your (new) column `pid` with the relevant data, and then add your `CONSTRAINT`.